# Bluetooth 5.0 on Linux with Qt. Problems compared to BT4.x

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I got a Bluetooth LE program running with Qt on Linux to talk to a Nordic nrf52 device. I originally started with a laptop that had a BT4.0 module, then switched to a laptop with 4.2 to take advantage of the larger MTU. All was fine, I set up a custom service with two characteristics and transferred 240 byte packets from laptop to Nordic.

I have recently got an LG Gram 17 - again running Linux - that is struggling. I can scan and connect just fine to devices, but Qt [and/or Bluez] is not picking up all the services and the characteristics are coming back with incorrect handles.

So, with the BT4.x laptops, when connecting to my nrf device it would pick up standard service 1800 and 1801 and my custom characteristic with its UUID.

Then selecting the custom service I would get two characteristics with handles 0x10 and 0x13.

However, when using the identical program on the new laptop with a BT5.0 module, I only see services 1801 and my custom service and my custom service returns two characteristics with different handles.

I used tcpdump to look at Bluetooth traffic and the two 4.x traffic is quite different to the 5.0. With the 4.x devices I can see it specifically talk to the correct BT address and even mentions the device name. With the new laptop that has a BT5 module, no such traffic seems to be recorded.

I have Googled this and can see nothing that says there should be problems. I can use a Light Blue program running n a OnePlus 6 phone, which has BT5.0 and that is able to write to my custom characteristic just fine. I set a breakpoint on the Nordic and the data sent from the phone running BT5.0 gets into the Nordic. From the laptop it does not. This leads me to believe the issue is with something on the laptop, not with BT5.0 or the Nordic.

FWIW:

```
bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.50
```

Qt version is 5.12.2.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or maybe even tell me that Bluez and/or Qt cannot cope with BT5.0 I'd be most grateful.  If there is any other information that would be helpful please let me know and I will supply it.

**Edit: I have solved this by using the UUIDs, not the handles that Qt/Bluez picks up from the characteristics it finds. I don't know whether this issue with Qt or Bluez. If I find out, I will post back.**

Comment: I don't know about Qt but BlueZ should cope with BT5.0 just fine. Did the version of bluetoothctl change when switching between the laptops?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; yes, it's 5.50 on the new machine, 5.45 on the old one.

Comment: Well there have been many changes to bluetoothctl between versions 5.45 and 5.50, including changes that are specific to the GATT portion of the app and the underlying D-Bus API. It is possible that what you are seeing is a result of these changes. If you have written the Qt program yourself then my suggestion is to get the same behaviour as before with bluetoothctl and then updating the Qt application to match that. If you haven't written the Qt program yourself, my recommendation is that you check whether it is supposed to work with the newer version of bluetoothctl.

Comment: It is, indeed, a Qt program that I wrote. I have been looking through what information bluetoothctl gives when you connect with the two versions; so far I can't even make out where you get the handle, but using  list-attributes, for example, I get identical information. I suspect from what you've said, though, bluetoothctl is where the difference lies.